# How can we prove that the derivative is the best approximation of rate of change?

Tags: calculus, limits, physics

I am a Physics Student so learning about derivatives is most essential, but how can you use this "derivative" to calculate Speeds and other such things accurately just by applying limits.

Note: I already know about epsilon-delta definition and the standard definition of a derivative, the graphic interpretation too but this doesn't satisfies me enough that how can I use the construct such as "derivative" for studying motion of objects and other such things.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! You need Taylor's formula for that. In another approach to differentiation, this property *is*, in a sense, the definition.

Comment: How are you defining the rate of change?

Comment: Maybe chapters 5 ("Time and Distance") and 7 ("Motion") in [vol. I of the Feynman Lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_toc.html) would help.

Comment: @Bernard :Did Sir Newton knew about Taylor's formula or did he had any other approach?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Welcome, the rate of change is here in the sense used to calculate speeds.

Comment: Taylor's formula was established at the time of Sir Isaac.